# Scaling features by using polynomial features

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, knn, non-linear-regression

I understand the concept of polynomial regression and the use of PolynomialFeatures by sklearn.

But to get a concrete hold over the concept of using PolynomialFeature expansion, I just wanted to ask about a scenario.

Here, I want to consider a scenario of polynomial features with KNN instead of regression.

This is how we use polynomialFeatures for regression.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_T, y_T, random_state = 0)
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
X_T_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_T)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_T_poly, y_T, random_state = 0)
fin = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Now, what if I do this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_T, y_T, random_state = 0)
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
X_T_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_T)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_T_poly, y_T, random_state = 0)
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = n)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

In former we are doing regression (I get it. OK) and in later we are using KNN.

1. Does it make sense to apply KNN here and is right(in the first place)?
2. How are the features being transformed in case of KNN?

After going into **.fit_transform()** I found this:

The function has noting to do with coefficients and intercepts.

```
def fit_transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
    """Fit to data, then transform it.
    Fits transformer to X and y with optional parameters fit_params
    and returns a transformed version of X.
    Parameters
    ----------
    X : numpy array of shape [n_samples, n_features]
        Training set.
    y : numpy array of shape [n_samples]
        Target values.
    Returns
    -------
    X_new : numpy array of shape [n_samples, n_features_new]
        Transformed array.
    """
    # non-optimized default implementation; override when a better
    # method is possible for a given clustering algorithm
    if y is None:
        # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
        return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    else:
        # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
```

So is it ok to do such practice of using PolynomialFeatures with KNN as above?

Comment: Polynomial Features created in both case are same and `Linear Regression` assume a linear relationship between X and Y whereas  best-known non-parametric
methods, `K-nearest neighbors regression (KNN)` makes no such assumption so it is okay to use it from my perspective.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong. We use polynomial features when we have two data points associate with a label [dimension we say]. ie one of the data point don't have a label explicitly.

Comment: Let's say if we have two columns of data `[a, b]` then a polynomial feature of 2 will give columns `[a, b, a*b, a*a, b*b]`. So, now we have more mixture and combination of data which might give better results.

Comment: I know this. I am trying to say suppose X = [a,b,c] and you scale X with degree of 2 or any but not 3. Does it makes sense?